# Facebook is not compressing Java Script files used in Like and Comment Plugin

Tags: facebook, plugins

I have added like and comment plugin on my website after that I ran Google PageSpeed test on my website and found that facebook is not compressing(gzip) these files.Any solution for this problem??.
Here is the Page Speed log-

> Compressing the following resources with gzip could reduce their
>   transfer size by 503KiB (70% reduction). Compressing
>   https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yq/r/1dpTPg3-Gwj.js could save
>   104.9KiB (70% reduction). Compressing https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yS/r/EqrQ6chk3oV.js could save
>   78.8KiB (70% reduction). Compressing https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yX/r/8ihoH7VyxDy.js could save
>   49.7KiB (68% reduction). Compressing https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yw/r/eNJGemJDFDG.js could save
>   47.5KiB (68% reduction). Compressing https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yN/r/YJ95GPV2FfL.css could
>   save 41.2KiB (79% reduction). Compressing
>   https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yX/r/GmIemdygsom.js could save
>   41KiB (71% reduction). Compressing
>   https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yY/r/ywd-QGzPSz7.js could save
>   34.7KiB (72% reduction). Compressing https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yB/r/ueivlZrc8P3.js could save
>   31.7KiB (68% reduction). Compressing https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yu/r/nY11W6zUi86.js could save
>   23.4KiB (67% reduction). Compressing https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y4/r/LqRjvpLXkFu.js could save
>   20.1KiB (69% reduction). Compressing https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y3/r/0LHuDDwkW7E.js could save
>   8.4KiB (63% reduction). Compressing https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y0/r/JNeGjL1jGuG.js could save
>   7KiB (58% reduction). Compressing
>   https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yv/r/xc_QQ9rZ9Si.js could save
>   4.8KiB (64% reduction). Compressing https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y9/r/EF8l4WMw2si.js could save
>   4.2KiB (60% reduction). Compressing https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yc/r/4RaPARYaYn2.js could save
>   3.4KiB (63% reduction).

Answer (score 0):

I was also concerned about this, until I read google's own product forum, where everybody was complaining about this pagespeed tool and specifically those uncompressed things that are actually external. I use firefox with firebug and yslow and think it's more reliable than pagespeed. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/Kz-9lxPw9VI%5B851-875-false%5D

Comment: External or not, it still affect page loading speed, and that's why the tool is recommending against uncompressed things.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution to this problem is very simple. Perhaps you keep this site:

```
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1'/>
```

If removed would increase sharply the speed of your site
In fact, I have also been using asynchronous but still be a barrier to speeding